# How to retrieve the actual stored procedure code in DB2 via DatabaseMetadata api in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, db2

I am writing a tool to compare two schemas in Java and print the result in command line.
I am able to retrieve the procedure names, parameters, type etc., but not the data, plz let me know if it is possible to return the actual content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the methods available (and not available) in java.sql.DatabaseMetaData, you will need to obtain the procedure body yourself, by directly querying the appropriate catalog table/view. On DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows platforms, that information is in the SYSCAT.ROUTINES view.